# Naming Problems in Python

Tags: python

In Zed Shaw's "Learn Python the Hard Way" tutorial 46, students are asked to create 
a `tests/NAME_tests.py` file. But I got `/` is not a valid character error in Aptana Studios
and Notepad++. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code that Zed asks to put into that file.

```
from nose.tools import *
import NAME

def setup():
    print "SETUP!"

def teardown():
    print "TEAR DOWN!"

def test_basic():
    print "I RAN!
```

Comment: can you show us some of your code?

Comment: If you are using Windows you might need to name it "tests\NAME_tests.py".

Comment: Just create a folder called `tests` and create a file called `NAME_tests.py` inside it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By

```
tests/NAME_tests.py
```

It's to create a file named `NAME_tests.py` under a folder named `tests`.

### UPDATE

An excerpt from *Learn Python The Hard Way* confirming the final structure:

```
setup.py
NAME/
    __init__.py
bin/
docs/
tests/
    NAME_tests.py
    __init__.py
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you cite errors from the editors, not in the code, it sounds like you might be trying to save a file literally called "tests/NAME_tests.py".

That only works if you already have a tests subdirectory in the current directory the file save dialog shows.

If you don't, create that first, navigate into it, then save the file as NAME_tests.py.